# highstock: not working the "upLineColor"

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the color of certain candles. 
Add parameter 'upLineColor' in series. 
It does not work.

```
var data = [
    {
        x : 1357624860000,
        open: 1,
        close: 2,
        low: 0.5,
        high: 3,
        //lineColor: "#FF0000",
        upLineColor: "#00FF00",
    },
    {
        x : 1357624920000,
        open: 2,
        close: 1.5,
        low: 0.5,
        high: 2,
        lineColor: "#FF0000",
        //upLineColor: "#00FF00",
    }
];

$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        name: 'test',
        data: data
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6wxt7q16/

Comment: What color is it you want to change? When do you want it to be different?

Comment: `upLineColor` should be set on the `series` level, not on the `point`. Just like in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.candlestick.upLineColor). Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/candlestick-linecolor/).

Comment: I want to change the color of one point. "color" works, "upColor" not working. If the candle is white, then ok, if black, the color does not change. In the example of the first candle is white, the other black.